# Custom Image for Submit Button not showing up

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to customize a Submit button for my Contact Form. I seem to be missing something. The link for my image doesn't seem to be showing up? Can someone please help me out and maybe point out what I am doing wrong or what I may be missing?

Here is the code:

```
    <li id="emf-li-post-button" class="left">
<input type="image" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" scr="http://andreethier.webs.com/Website/submit.png" 
value="submit.png" onmouseover="return true;" /></li>
```

Comment: you typed "scr=" instead of "src="

Comment: If an answer solved your issue please set it as the answer. if not edit your question and provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw8ac/):

```
<li id="emf-li-post-button" class="left" style="list-style: none;">
  <input type="image" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" src="http://andreethier.webs.com/Website/submit.png" value="submit.png" onmouseover="return true;" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `input type="submit"` if you want to submit a form.

**HTML**

```
<li id="emf-li-post-button" class="left">
  <input type="submit" onmouseover="return true;" value="Text" />
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#emf-li-post-button input {
    background: url('http://andreethier.webs.com/Website/submit.png') no-repeat top left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielweyer/adKwH/